# Securing a REST call to Vault Secrets management

Tags: rest, ssh, tls1.2, hashicorp-vault

Been trying to figure out how to do this for awhile. Essentially, Vault does not have a secure option for its REST calls. I want to make these rest calls encrypted from as close between point a and b as possible. My thoughts have been the following:

- Use an SSH tunnel
- Use a TLS tunnel like Stunnel

I currently have Vault in a Docker container, so that’s something else to mention. Has anyone encountered this situation, and how did you deal with it?

UPDATE: So, using the Python API (HVAC), I am getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0',
port=8200): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/secret (Caused by
SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record',
'wrong version number')],)",),))
```

Using the following commands:

```
import os
import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url='https://0.0.0.0:8200', token='my-token-here')
```

Answer (score 3):

Vault has [TLS enabled by default](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/listener/tcp.html#tls_disable), thus all your REST calls are encrypted already. If you are having trouble using https, have a look at the documentation of `VAULT_CACERT` and `VAULT_CAPATH` environment variables.

from vault's documentation.

> VAULT_CACERT
>
> Path to a PEM-encoded CA certificate file on the local disk. This file
>   is used to verify the Vault server's SSL certificate. This environment
>   variable takes precedence over VAULT_CAPATH.
>
> VAULT_CAPATH Path to a directory of PEM-encoded CA certificate files
>   on the local disk. These certificates are used to verify the Vault
>   server's SSL certificate.

You can use tools like `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to make sure that your requests are indeed encrypted.

Comment: have you configured vault with proper `CA` certificate before initialising it?

Comment: I am using Vault inside a Docker container. How do I setup the CA prior to initializing it?

Comment: you can still set them through environment variables. please have a read, https://hub.docker.com/_/vault/

Comment: There is a catch here. If you are fetching credentials from Vault , you are actually fetching it from Vault backend(probably Consul). So along with ensuring that your application is communicating with Vault over SSL also ensure that Vault -> Consul(or any other backend) communication is also over SSL. Is is important to secure the entire pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate for Vault running in a container, you need to create a configuration file for Vault that contains something similar to this this (Chef/Ruby code):

```
config_content = %(
  "storage": {
     ...
  },
  "default_lease_ttl": "768h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "8766h",
  "listener": [
    {"tcp": {
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable": 0,
      "tls_cert_file": "/vault/certs/my-cert-combined.pem",
      "tls_key_file": "/vault/certs/my-cert.key"
    }}],
  "log_level": "info"
 )
```

Especially the listener portion. Make your backend storage whatever you want to use (not the Dev default of in-memory!).

Note you will need to get a valid certificate and its private key also in the volume bound into the container.

Store this configuration file in a directory that gets bound inside the container to the path /vault/config. I use /var/vault/config on my host. For example (more Ruby/Chef):

```
docker_container 'vault' do
  container_name 'vault'
  tag 'latest'
  port '8200:8200'
  cap_add ['IPC_LOCK']
  restart_policy 'always'
  volumes ['/var/vault:/vault']
  command 'vault server -config /vault/config'
  action :run_if_missing
end
```

That command tells Vault to look in /vault/config and it should find your config file there, with a .json extension. Note it is important to have the config file listener->tcp->address be 0.0.0.0, rather than 127.0.0.1, because Vault will not resolve external accesses properly.

Then Vault will startup with TLS encryption on all transactions. Define VAULT_ADDR to have https://your-host.com:8200 and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've been testing it on my local environment. So instead of calling the secured https: `https://localhost:8200`, I called regular http: `http://localhost:8200`.
This solved the error.